# How can i apply a style only to the selected elements by clicking a button in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

i'm a super noob in Blazor and i need to create a control just like the one in this editor meaning if i select text i can change the color, typography, italics etc. but only for that selected element(s). I tried to do that with an if condition to change a bool variable when the **B**, *I* or typography button is clicked, problem is that of course it changed to every element that has the if condition.

So my question is in Blazor how can i know which element is selected so that i can only apply this styles to that element?

What i have so far is this in which the navbar changes if texts is selected is shows bold, italic buttons and if canvas is selected it shows the other navbar.

```
<nav hidden="@(canvasToolbar)" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="/docs/5.1/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="30" height="24">
            TEXT
        </a>
        <button @onclick="@bold"><b>B</b></button>
        <button @onclick="@italic"><b>I</b></button>
    </div>
</nav>

<nav hidden="@(textToolbar)" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="/docs/5.1/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
            CANVAS
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>

<p style="color: purple; font-weight:@isBold" @onfocus="@(e => { isBold = true; })" @onclick="@ShowTextToolbar">HH</p>
   
<button style="color: red; font-weight:@(isBold ? "bold" : string.Empty)" @onclick="@ShowTextToolbar">Hello</button>
<div style="color: orange" @onclick="@ShowCanvasToolbar">Show Canvas toolbar</div>

@code{
    private bool textToolbar { get; set; } = true;
    private bool canvasToolbar { get; set; } = false;

    private bool isBold { get; set; } = false;
    private bool isItalic { get; set; } = false;

    [Parameter] public string CssStyles { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback TextBold { get; set; }

    private void ShowTextToolbar()
    {
        textToolbar = true;
        canvasToolbar = false;
    }

    private void ShowCanvasToolbar()
    {
        canvasToolbar = true;
        textToolbar = false;
    }

    private async Task bold()
    {
        isBold = !isBold;
    }

    private void italic()
    {
        isItalic = !isItalic;
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: I’m not using any library and by this editor i mean what i described like a text editor where you can put color, or bold/ italic style to the selected text.

Comment: [Review] - You need to put some example code in your question and demonstrate what you have have so far.

Comment: Hi i've added the code, thanks for your  observation :)